# Android NDK socket creation null pointer

Tags: android, c, sockets, nullpointerexception, android-ndk

For adding TCP-socket-options, I need to use the C-sockets of Android NDK instead of Java sockets. The following function is called by a button-click-event.

When creating such a socket, the syscall leads me to a null pointer (see log output at the end).

As the log shows, the line above gets called (Create Socket) but then (so it has to be in the socket()-call), the app crashes due to a null pointer before it is possible to evaluate the return value.

What did I do wrong?

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity"

void error(const char *msg)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", msg);
    exit(0);
}


int Java_com_example_ndk1_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity_sendUrgent(JNIEnv * env, jobject this,
        jstring jurl, int portno, jstring jdata, jboolean jSetUrgentFlag)
{

    int sockfd = 0;
    error("Create Socket");
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    error("Socket created");
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    return 1;
}



05-18 14:47:54.002  11500-11500/com.example.ndk1 D/NDK_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity﹕ NDK:LC: [Create Socket]
05-18 14:47:54.022     780-1221/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{42bde4f8 u0 com.example.ndk1/com.example.ndk1.AndroidNDK1SampleActivity}
05-18 14:47:54.022     780-1222/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.ndk1 (pid 11500) has died.
05-18 14:47:54.022     780-1222/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{42ae6278 u0 com.example.ndk1/.AndroidNDK1SampleActivity t17}: app died, no saved state
05-18 14:47:54.062     988-1000/? W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)


dmesg-log:
<3>[11101.768759] init: untracked pid 11500 exited
```

Comment: The error message you post provides no direct indication of what has failed - rather it is merely a consequence of the process vanishing.  You will have to either find a more informative message in the logs such as a native stack trace, or solve the problem by inspection of the code.

Comment: This is exactly my problem... Since socket() is a system call, I have no influence on its code and therefore cannot debug into it.
I've included the system log message, but it also says nothing.

Comment: You should print `errno,` or call `perror(),` or use `strerror()` in the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "exit(0)" from the void error() functions

Comment: thanks - it worked. Maybe the tutorial I used wasn't that good